# How can I get the path of the file followed by its name and extension when it is opened by my Python application from the file-manager?

Tags: python, linux

1- I want to add my Python application to the open-with list of an extension like .ext

2- when the user open .ext extension from the file manager, I want my Python application to store the path of the opened file followed by its filename and extension to a text file.

3- I want my application to pass the line stored inside the created text-file to a text-box inside the main window of my Python application.

I will use Tkinter or GTK 3.0 for the main window of my Python application, because it will be a simple application.

My project will be written to be executed on Linux, so please keep that in mind before answering my question.

Comment: What DWM are you on?

Comment: I use Mutter right now. Does it matter?

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3/library/dialog.html. It will get you started on your goal.

Comment: I want when I open a file from the file manager using my application to get the path of that file + file-name + extension.

Comment: `How can I get the path of the file followed by its name and extension when it is opened by my Python application from the file-manager?` When something _is opened_ with your python application, why do you care about file-manager? What do you mean? Just query the opened file in your python application, it has already opened it. I believe, you want to associate specific file extension with specific application to run it.

Comment: My Python application is not programmed to open files, and I actually do not know how can I do that using Python. I just want my application to query the path, the filename, and the extension of the opened file, then the user choose how to open the file, and press Run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer to my second question, and I will share it here:

```
import sys
sys.argv[1:]
```

When a file is opened using my application, it is opened like this:

python3 /location-to-my-python-script/my-python-script.py /location-to-the-file/filename.ext

`sys.argv` = /location-to-my-python-script/my-python-script.py /location-to-the-file/filename.ext

`sys.argv[0]` = /location-to-my-python-script/my-python-script.py

`sys.argv[1:]` = /location-to-the-file/filename.ext

Answer (score 0):

First you have to create a mime type for the extension. Basically https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/564816/how-to-install-a-new-custom-mime-type-on-my-linux-system-using-cli-tools . https://specifications.freedesktop.org/mime-apps-spec/mime-apps-spec-latest.html . Or it's already an existing mime type, dunno.

Then you have to create a `.desktop` file that handles that mime type. https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/ . Use `~/. local/share/applications` for custom location. Use `Exec=yourapp %f` or with `%U` depending on your application.

Then you have to register that desktop file as default, but when it's a new type it should be picked by itself. After that, `xdg-open` should pick your `.desktop` file.

Comment: That answered my first question. Thanks.